# Block direct access to files into subfolder, but allow to index page with htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess, blocking, http-referer

I have a lot of folders and subfolder in my domain. I want to avoid direct access to files types html/ jpg/ gif/ etc in a specific subfolders, but I want it to be accessible by a index.php page.

Structure is something like:

- www.domain.com/folder1
- www.domain.com/folder2
- www.domain.com/folder2/subfolder1
- **www.domain.com/folder2/subfolder2**
- **www.domain.com/folder2/subfolder2/index.php**
- **www.domain.com/folder2/subfolder2/page1.html**
- **www.domain.com/folder2/subfolder2/page2.html**
- **www.domain.com/folder2/subfolder2/images/1.jpg**
- **www.domain.com/folder2/subfolder2/images/2.jpg**

I tryed to put page1.html, page2.html and images folder inside a new folder called **blocked_content**:

- www.domain.com/folder2/subfolder2/index.php
- www.domain.com/folder2/subfolder2/**blocked_content**/page1.html

and added a .htaccess with `deny from all` and `Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all` inside **blocked_content** folder. It blocked all, even index.php can't access the files inside this. Index.php only has simple links as `<a href="blocked_content/page1.html">`

Tryed this config on .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(swf|pdf|css|gif|png|jpg|html|htm)$ - [F]
```

And put it inside subfolder2 and got no effect.

Tryed this config on .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.com/folder2/subfolder2 [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(swf|pdf|css|gif|png|jpg|html|htm)$ - [F]
```

I put it inside subfolder2: No effect. I put it in root directory it blocks all other folders.

I searched a lot. I'm stucked. What am I doing wrong? Putting htacess in wrong places or forgeting to add something? I want to do this by .htacess if it is possible. Include php sessions to all html files will not work because I can't change the file names.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly you want to block all requests but to `index.php` and only return other resources when the `index.php` site is rendered in browser and the content is requested by browser? If that is the case, it cannot be done (not securely, at least). The user can always change any headers you might check.

Comment: I found a way to do what I want in they way I was trying. Found a tool to generate .htaccess file and it worked! But how user can change headers, Mikulas? Which way would be a secure way?

Comment: If that is the case, please either post the solution as an answer here on Stack Overflow or close the question. Changing headers can be done by creating custom requests, for example with `curl` (http://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: I really appreciate your help, Mikulas! I will study more about it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found way to do this the way I was trying.

Used a Web Tool to generate this .htaccess in this website [PREVENT HOTLINKING OF IMAGES – HOW TO HOTLINK PROTECT](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/)

Put the .htaccess into my **blocked_content/** folder.

The index.php inside my domain can access everything into this folder, but a user cannot type the url on browser as a hotlink. eg: **www.domain.com/folder2/subfolder2/blocked_content/images/1.jpg**

The difference between the new .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(swf|pdf|css|gif|png|jpg|html|htm)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

To the old one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(swf|pdf|css|gif|png|jpg|html|htm)$ - [F]
```

PS: @Mikulas Dite told me it may be not so secure as I hope.

Comment: Great reference!
Would be a most secure way protect each file with php session if I was able to do this?

Comment: It definitely would be (as long as you store SID in cookies and do not have an XSS on your site), but it would bring so much overhead it's probably not worth it. Unless you are rendering some classified data and it's not customary.

Comment: My current project is not classified too much, but I will keep this in mind for another project! Thanks you very much, Mikulas, for your help!